# Old install of ACRA just shows null in the Google spreadsheet

Tags: android, acra

I am getting back to updating a certain app after about 2 years of only minimally updating it, and the error reporting with ACRA now doesn't seem to work.

It used to populate a Google spreadsheet for me with errors, but now as you can see from this screenshot, it just puts blanks or nulls in there:

[image]

Would anyone know how to fix this? Now I am using acra-4.2.3.jar in my libs folder. Should I update the jar or would something else fix the issue?

Comment: At Google's request, spreadsheet logging support was deprecated a while ago.

Comment: @CommonsWare I saw something like that, but what did they say to do as an alternative?

Comment: There are plenty of online services that work with ACRA. You can host Acralyzer somewhere, which is ACRA's official Couchbase-based server app. You can configure ACRA to send emails via the user's email client. Or you can roll your own backend. [Here's a 13-line Ruby script for it](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ACRA/Simple/stub_server.rb) that just logs the JSON of the reports to a designated directory. See also https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Backends

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you - what is the way to have the exceptions sent to an email? Is there a tutorial for that?

Comment: https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-by-email